# After simple Linq-Foreach List is null

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, foreach

Right now I'm totally weird!
I want to remove some ViewModels of my ObservableCollection:

```
    var AllConnectedPlugs = from VM_Element in AllElements
                            from Plug in VM_Element.Element.AllPlugs
                            where VMs_ToDelete.Any(VM_Connection => VM_Connection.Connection.SourcePlug == Plug || VM_Connection.Connection.DestinationPlug == Plug)
                            select Plug;

    MessageBox.Show(VMs_ToDelete.ToList().Count.ToString()); //x
    AllConnectedPlugs.ToList().ForEach(Plug => Plug.Connection = null);
    MessageBox.Show(VMs_ToDelete.ToList().Count.ToString()); //0
    VMs_ToDelete.ToList().ForEach(VM_Connection => AllConnections.Remove(VM_Connection));
```

The Code works fine - I get the right VM and so on. But after my `foreach` the list VMs_ToDelete is empty.

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't show where you initialize `VMs_ToDelete`. It's never populated in the code you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AllConnectedPlugs` connections as IEnumerable, so it's executed everytime you accessing it. After assigning Connection to null, query returns empty collection. This will solve your problem:

```
var AllConnectedPlugs = (from VM_Element in AllElements
                        from Plug in VM_Element.Element.AllPlugs
                        where VMs_ToDelete.Any(VM_Connection => VM_Connection.Connection.SourcePlug == Plug || VM_Connection.Connection.DestinationPlug == Plug)
                        select Plug).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both collections appeal to the same references. Every element in collection VMs_ToDelete have same reference of elements in AllConnections.
If you removing this element from AllConnection collection you also removing him from VMs_ToDelete collection, becouse you are removing source element.

In linq queries exists Deferred Execution and Lazy Evaluation in LINQ mechanism = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx.

You can fix this problem by creating for example list or array from this query (.Tolist(), .ToArray(), etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your VMs_ToDelete variable is a query, not the result of it. You get the result when you request it, for example, by using .ToList().

So, if you execute the query after removing the items from the source, obviously no items will be found, since they are ready removed.

To solve this, append a .ToList() after the query so you have the results and not the query in your VMs_Delete variable.